# Arrange months under year php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been grinding my gears on this one. See [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103929/make-one-query-and-then-another-based-on-the-first?noredirect=1#comment54022973_33103929) on the same topic. It seems as this is a tough one to solve. But, i found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366895/group-by-month-and-year-in-mysql), and it seems as Derek Adair has managed to make a json out of the same problem.

**My question is**:

How can i from this query

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year
FROM
    MOCK_DATA
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) DESC
```

Get the result either a json array, or obecjt(stdClass)

```
{
  "2009":["August","July","September"],
  "2010":["January", "February", "October"]
}
```

Because now i get the following result:

```
Array(35) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#19 (2) {
["month"]=> string(8) "December" 
["year"]=> string(4) "2013" } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#20 (2) { 
["month"]=> string(8) "November" 
["year"]=> string(4) "2013" } . . . .
```

And the expected result is something like:

```
2013
jan
feb
...etc
2014
jan
feb
..etc
2015
jan
feb
..etc
```

Comment: after fetching data from query, use a forloop and do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MONTHNAME( DATE ) AS 
MONTH , YEAR( DATE ) AS YEAR
FROM mdata
GROUP BY YEAR( DATE ) , MONTH( DATE ) DESC ");
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) { 
    $m = $row[0];
    $y = $row[1];
    if(!isset($data[$y]) ) {
        $data[$y] = array();
    }
    $data[$y][] = $m;
}
echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
```

and the result is

```
Array
(
    [1997] => Array
        (
            [0] => February
        )

    [2004] => Array
        (
            [0] => October
        )

    [2015] => Array
        (
            [0] => October
            [1] => March
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with thanks to the accepted answer!

```
        $sql = "SELECT MONTHNAME(date) as month, YEAR(date) as year FROM MOCK_DATA GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) DESC";
        $query = $database->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();

        $data = array();

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $m = $row['month'];
    $y = $row['year'];
    if(!isset($data[$y]) ) {
        $data[$y] = array();
    }
    $data[$y][] = $m;
}

        return $data;
```

And this is how i print it:

```
echo '<br>Years and months<br>';
foreach($this->arrange as $year => $yearMonths) {
    echo '<b>Year: '.$year.'</b><br>';
    foreach($yearMonths as $month) {
        echo 'Month: '.$month.'<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
echo '<br>Only years<br>';
foreach($this->arrange as $year => $yearMonths) {
    echo '<b>Year: '.$year.'</b><br>';
}
```